# Test error handling method weirdness with Junit5 and mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I'm making unit tests for a method that does some exception handling. here's the simplified class I'd like to test:

```
class Foo{

    private BarService bar;

    public int MethodToTest(){

        try{
            bar.methodThatThrows();
            return 1;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the unit test class.

```
class FooTest{

    private IBarService barService = mock(BarService.class);

    @Test
    TestMethodToTest(){

        when(barService.methodThatThrows()).thenThrow(new Exception("message");
        Foo foo = new foo();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "barService", barService);
        assertEquals(foo.MethodToTest(), 0);
    }
}
```

Somehow, when I run it, it fails because there is an error thrown (as expected), which has the exact same message as the message I put into the mocked service. When I run in debug mode, the catch block is not even run. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are throwing a checked exception in your test that is not declared for `methodThatThrows`

A message you declared in your test is indeed printed to the console, but the message is more informative:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.lang.Exception: message
```

For example (IOException declared in BarService, but a more general checked exception thrown in the test code):

```
public class BarService {
    public int methodThatThrows() throws IOException {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example how that would look like?

Comment: Could be it. But the exception I throw in the mocked object is of the same type as expected and caught. I'm not seeing the message you describe

Comment: Can you stop in the test and step into Method to test? As pointed out in another comment, the code you posted is perfectly fine, so you may also true to prepare a complete, verifiable example.

Comment: Found it. Type of exception I put in catch and the type of exception I put in the thenThrows were different. Same name, different package

Answer (score -1):

You're not setting the `BarService` correctly in your example code.  You're doing:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "barService", barService);
```

But in the `Foo` class, the `BarService` variable is called "bar", and not "barService", so you need to do:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(foo, "bar", barService);
```

Though the "correct" way to do this is to use Spring to autowire `BarService` into `Foo`, which allows you to avoid having to use `ReflectionTestUtils` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. Though this is fake code, (cannot expose). In the real code the DI just works, hence there is an exception thrown (the one mocked). You have an explanation for the question I actually asked?

Comment: I could only base my answer on the code you provided, which was not correctly initializing your `Foo` object.  Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Because, once a few syntax errors were fixed, the sample code that you posted above passes the unit test with flying colors.  Which means that whatever's causing the issue is that you're seeing is not present in the sample you provided.